# Is there a way to take away focus in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, focus, javafx-2, nodes

I know that your can give focus to a node in javafx by doing *node.requestFocus();* but is there a way to take away focus from a node in javafx or prevent focus on an object?

Comment: Typically I think something always has the focus. So the only way I can see to do this is to request focus to something else. Why do you want to remove focus though? Would disabling the node work for what you want to do?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't think there's any guarantee this will always work, but you can try setting focus to something that inherently doesn't accept keyboard input (such as a layout pane):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class NoFocusTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField tf1 = new TextField();
        tf1.setPromptText("Enter something");
        TextField tf2 = new TextField();
        tf2.setPromptText("Enter something else");
        VBox root = new VBox(5, tf1, tf2);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 250, 150));
        primaryStage.show();
        root.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

```
node = new node() {
  public void requestFocus() { }
};
```

Now this will override the focus and the node will NEVER be able to have focus. You could also (as stated before) disable the node with:

```
node.setDisable(true);
```

If you need focus later:

```
node.setDisable(false);
node.requestFocus();
```

I decided to update my answer to this with one more option.
If you are giving another node focus at the start of the program you could set a particular node to be non-traversable and it will not gain focus.

```
node.setFocusTraversable(false);
```

Comment: Well not sure what you mean by node.setFocusTraversible(true) because setting it true will allow a node to have focus.

Comment: I search how able the focus, you solution help me to find the solution to my problem, thanks

Comment: @PhilipVaughn how to request focus textfield in FXML?

Comment: @UnKnown Sorry it's been like 8 months since you commented but if you still have a question about TextField focus you should ask a brand new question because that's actually something that could take a bit of code depending on WHEN you need the control to have focus.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another node then you can remove focus from your node and give it to another with this.

```
otherNode.requestFocus();
```

By doing this you won't need to disable or enable your original node.

Some nodes such as a Label won't look different when they have focus, so this can make it appear as if focus was removed.