# JavaFX relative to Swing setFocusable(true/false)?

Tags: java, javafx, focus

I am trying to find some way to **make an UI Control unfocusabe** in JavaFX:

Is there something similar to Swing or do I have to override some method?

**UPDATE:**

**I want to make the control not focusable at all and not change the focus  to another `Node`.**

What you can do is:

```
node.setFocusTraversable(false);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to take away focus in javafx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431959/is-there-a-way-to-take-away-focus-in-javafx)

Comment: What kind of control do you want to make unfocusable?

Comment: @Uluk Biy keyListener of a panel or windows isn't working in Swing if the focus is into a component for example JButton or JSlider and so i was making these components unFocusable().As i passed on javaFX i see that  this has changed and i am wandering how(I mean even if the focus is on the component the keyListener of parent is working)...Let me know if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `Node` from basically every Control inherits the `focusProperty()`. You can bind something to that property or add a ChangeListener to detect when focus is lost:

```
focusedProperty().addListener((observalbe, oldFocusedState, newFocusedState) -> {
  System.out.println("Control changed focused state from "+oldFocusedState+"->"+newFocusedState);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe what you want is the `editable` property
@see [TextField#setEditable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#setEditable-boolean-)!

Answer (score 0):

I've already answered this question. Please check it out.

This will show you how to remove focus forever on a node, remove it for a time, OR make the node not traversable.

[Is there a way to take away focus in javafx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431959/is-there-a-way-to-take-away-focus-in-javafx/25467653#25467653)