# How to change the initial color of my JFXButton?

Tags: javafx, jfoenix

I'm working on my database project, I have added 2 JFXButton one for exit and the other to minimize the application, I have added CSS style as transparent, but when it appears on the screen one is having a different color from the other although I copy the button and it has the same parent for both

[image].

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution
Scene builder -> Properties -> Focus traversable (disable)

[image]

Comment: I don't know if this is the solution you want or if it makes sense. I guess it's fine if you are okay with that button not having focus via the `Tab-Button`. Another things you could have done is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431959/is-there-a-way-to-take-away-focus-in-javafx